# antonym for "partisan"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/partisan) lists the following antonyms for 'partisan':

> - adversary
> - antagonist
> - opponent

These carry combative connotations.  Is there a good antonym for 'partisan' that is possibly etymologically related to (or carries minimal further connotation than) the concept of non-affiliation with reference to any given (not necessarily political) party?

Comment: *non-partisan*...

Comment: The opposite of 'member of a party' is 'not a member of a party': is this really what you are asking for? If not, some clarification would be useful.

Comment: My first thought was loyalist or non-sectarian, but agree some clarification is needed.

Comment: hey @TimLymington looking for a noun not a noun phrase.  other guys, go ahead and post as answer...

Comment: "Partisan" has several different meanings.

Comment: But of course "anarchist" would be a suitable antonym for some senses.

Comment: How about **neutral**?

Comment: hey @DanRomik I don't want to imply neutrality.  I don't want to imply an intrinsic bias toward nonpartisanship, rather, the quality of distinctly not belonging to any certain party.  For example, "Professor Bigg and his partisans thought the world was flat" would express an antonymic sense of the word I seek -- whatever would exclude one from "Professor Bigg's partisans", but go no further.

Comment: Your question is unclear as it stands. Please supply an example sentence with a blank where the word you want would work. Your explanation in the last comment is cogent, but seems to suggest the word you would use varies from context to context, or relies entirely on the context for its meaning.

Comment: That's just, like, your *opinion*, man.....

Comment: No, them's like the rules for questions asking for a single word on this site. Check out the help on asking a good question here.

Answer (score 1):

In US politics, a political candidate who is *not* affiliated with any particular party is called **independent**. (One could rightly argue that in politics, no one is truly independent, however...)

For political events and discussions, **non-partisan** is usually the term, at least in the US.

Both these terms appear to be used in Canadian politics as well.

Comment: I agree with you. I think independent is the word the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***maverick***?

> *n.* A person who shows independence of thought and action, especially by refusing to adhere to the policies of a group to which he or she belongs.
>
> *adj.* Characterized by or displaying independence of thought and action: maverick politicians; a maverick decision.
>
> [Possibly after Samuel Augustus Maverick, (1803-1870), American cattleman who left the calves in his herd unbranded .]
> [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Maverick)

Answer (score 0):

***Objective***, perhaps - *of a person or his or her judgement: not influenced by personal feelings or opinions in considering and representing facts; impartial, detached.* (OED)

Answer (score 0):

The antonyms you listed were for the noun usage or *partisan*:

> :  a firm adherent to a party, faction, cause, or person; especially
>   :  one exhibiting blind, prejudiced, and unreasoning allegiance
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partisan)</sub>

I would describe the antonym of such a person (in an non-combative way) as a ***skeptic***:

> : a person who questions or doubts something (such as a claim or statement
>   : a person who often questions or doubts things
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skeptic)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an antonym for the concept of someone with an unwavering party affiliation the choices in Roget's Thesaurus that look suitable are independent, neutral, swing voter or centrist.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic groups of antonyms for the noun form of partisan, which seems to be the form you are describing (a person or thing which is biased in favor of another).

The first group of terms describes people or things which are biased *against* another.

- critic   (e.g. "She is a persistent critic of the University of Chicago")
- knocker  (e.g. "He has been a Carter-knocker since the 70's")

The second group of terms describes people or things which are not biased towards or against any party, or are at least perceived to be so:

- disinterested party
- neutral party
- impartial person
- judge
- arbiter

The most common of these would probably be those two-word phrases, as the latter single words are generally meant to imply someone who is actively judging a thing, and is not just neutral to it.  Indeed, it's also common to expand those two-word phrases to emphasize the neutral nature of the person by noting they are a third party to a dispute or contest (e.g. "a neutral third party").

Comment: hey Mark, thanks for answering! Check out my comment to @Dan Romik under the question!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike 'nonpartisan', which in addition to meaning 'not partisan' is defined as "based on, influenced by, affiliated with, or supporting the interests or policies of no *single* political party" ([*American Heritage*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonpartisan), emphasis mine), the other and as yet unmentioned antonym means, more simply, the opposite of 'partisan':

> **unpartisan**, *adj.*
>   Not partisan; not supporting a cause, party, or person, esp. zealously or blindly.

["unpartisan, adj.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/418663?rskey=QoOwKm&result=8&isAdvanced=false (accessed January 22, 2016).]

This more minimal sense, while still closely related etymologically to 'partisan', does not signify 'non-affiliated with any *one* or any *single* party'; rather 'unpartisan' signifies an utter lack of affiliation.

Comment: thanks for answering -- check out my comment to @Dan Romik under the question!